# PHP namespaces and "use"

Tags: php, namespaces

I am having a little trouble with namespaces and the `use` statements.

I have three files: `ShapeInterface.php`, `Shape.php` and `Circle.php`.

I am trying to do this using relative paths so I have put this in all of the classes:

```
namespace Shape;
```

In my circle class I have the following:

```
namespace Shape;
//use Shape;
//use ShapeInterface;

include 'Shape.php';
include 'ShapeInterface.php';    

class Circle extends Shape implements ShapeInterface{ ....
```

If I use the `include` statements I get no errors. If I try the `use` statements I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Shape\Shape' not found in
>   /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/workspace/shape/Circle.php on line 8

Could someone please give me a little guidance on the issue?

Comment: Also concerning this subject - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341955/does-the-import-or-use-order-affect-functionality-in-php

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The [`use` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) is for giving aliases to names of classes, interfaces or other namespaces. Most `use` statements refer to a namespace or class that you'd like to shorten:

```
use My\Full\Namespace;
```

is equivalent to:

```
use My\Full\Namespace as Namespace;
// Namespace\Foo is now shorthand for My\Full\Namespace\Foo
```

If the `use` operator is used with a class or interface name, it has the following uses:

```
// after this, "new DifferentName();" would instantiate a My\Full\Classname
use My\Full\Classname as DifferentName;

// global class - making "new ArrayObject()" and "new \ArrayObject()" equivalent
use ArrayObject;
```

The `use` operator is not to be confused with [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload). A class is autoloaded (negating the need for `include`) by registering an autoloader (e.g. with `spl_autoload_register`). You might want to read [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) to see a suitable autoloader implementation.

Comment: So if i create another file called bootstrap.php and place an autoloader inside along with $circle = new Circle(); It includes the Circle.php but I am getting an error: Fatal error: Class 'Shape' not found in .../Circle.php on line 6. It appears to load Circle.php but not load Shape.php Circle is defined as: class Circle extends Shape implements ShapeInterface

Comment: If I remove the namespace from the above classes the autoloader works fine. However when I have namespace in the interface of shape class I get the above error

Comment: [Created a gist](https://gist.github.com/2658317) to give an example. Unfortunately gists can't have subfolders. Put the bootstrap.php in a folder and put the other classes in a subfolder named 'Shape'.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to order your code into namespaces, just use the keyword `namespace`:

file1.php

```
namespace foo\bar;
```

In file2.php

```
$obj = new \foo\bar\myObj();
```

You can also use `use`. If in file2 you put

`use foo\bar as mypath;`

you need to use `mypath` instead of `bar` anywhere in the file:

```
$obj  = new mypath\myObj();
```

Using `use foo\bar;` is equal to `use foo\bar as bar;`.