# PayPal PHP API breaks my script

Tags: php, paypal

I'm just starting to implement PayPal's PHP API into a website I'm building and I'm coming across an error. Whenever I include any of there php my page just dies with errors all resembling this

```
Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Common\PPModel' not found in /xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/libs/PayPal/Api/Amount.php on line 6
```

The start of Amount.php is this

```
<?php
namespace PayPal\Api;

use PayPal\Common\PPModel;

class Amount extends PPModel { //This is line number 6
```

What do the namespace and use commands do? I don't have a PayPal/Common/PPModel file anywhere, should I have one?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the Paypal API, but you can read about [namespace and use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542012/php-namespaces-and-use).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have not included class PayPal\Common\PPModel manually, or your __autoload function doesn't supports namespaces properly (at least Paypal namespace)
Whether you are using any framework?