# Does use statement order affect functionality in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

I've been using PHP's namespaces for some time now and I think it is a great addition to my programming. This morning I wondered about something concerning the `use` statement. I'm wondering if the order of `use` affects the functonality of my PHP code.

#### According to PHP.net

> The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias, or importing, is an important feature of namespaces. This is similar to the ability of unix-based filesystems to create symbolic links to a file or to a directory.
>
> AIn PHP, aliasing is accomplished with the use operator.

***~ That sucks, nothing about the order of inclusion. Let's ask my friends on SO!***

### Example

Below, I'll try to give a better example

#### Class C

```
namespace Fully\Qualified\Namespace;

use Fully\Qualified\Namespace\B;
use Fully\Qualified\Namespace\A;

class C
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Class B

```
namespace Fully\Qualified\Namespace;

use Fully\Qualified\Namespace\A;

class B extends A
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Class A

```
namespace Fully\Qualified\Namespace;

class A
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, will it give me trouble that class `B` is included before class `A` in my use statements?

Comment: Nope. Also, you can omit the starting \ when using `use`.

Comment: Agree leading backslash is officially discourage.

Comment: Yes, exact first backslash, the benefit is working with namespaces allows you to 'include' more than one objects with same name but different path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When alias namespaces no.

When used in the class body for Traits may affect in certain scenarios related with the use of docblock annotations.