# Uncaught Error: Class 'Document' not found

Tags: php, class, require

I want to divide the code I have written into smaller manageable files. One file has over 2500 lines and I think it might be better to put some of its code into a separate header file. However, as soon as I separate the code and run it. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Document' not found
```

Here is the code of my `large-file.php`:

```
<?php
require_once("common-head.php");

/* Some more code */
$document = new Document($document_html);
```

Here is the code of my `common-head.php`:

```
<?php
/* Some code */
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use DiDom\Document;
/* Some more code */
```

Both the files are located in the same directory so the path to `vendor/autoload.php` does not change. However, if the code is placed in separate files as I have shown above, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Document' not found
```

If I take all the code out of `common-head.php` and place it in my `large-file.php` in place of `require_once("common-head.php");`. It works without any error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you added the `diDim\Document` to the psr autoloader?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'Document' not found

the error means PHP is unable to find the class name 'Document' you are using in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `use` in same file.

```php
// large-file.php
use DiDom\Document;

require_once("common-head.php");

/* Some more code */
$document = new Document($document_html);
```

see - [PHP namespaces and "use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542012/php-namespaces-and-use)