# why Auth facade work when i use just use Auth and other class like Request doesn't work untill i write the whole directory

Tags: laravel, class, laravel-8

my question is why is laravel allow to just use `use Auth;` and don't have to write the whole directory but when I use other class like Request I have to write all directory like `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and not able to just write `use Request;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP namespaces and "use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542012/php-namespaces-and-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick note — in this context, `Illuminate\Http\Request` is a {namespace}\{class name}, not a directory.

**The Request Facade**

First, there absolutely is a [**Request facade**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#facade-class-reference). I can quickly demonstrate some basic functionality.

```php
use Request;

Request::merge(['foo' => 'bar']);

dd(Request::all());
```

```php
array:1 [▼
  "foo" => "bar"
]
```

You can achieve the same result using the `request()` helper, without the need to explicitly import the facade.

**Automatic Dependency Injection**

I suspect that your question may actually be referring to Laravel's automatic dependency injection. In this case, Laravel has already resolved and populated an `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance behind the scenes. It will only `->bind()` this instance to the method's `$request` parameter if it sees the correct type-hinting. This is why you are unable to simply import the facade.

```php
Route::get('sample/request', 'SampleController@update');
```

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SampleController
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        dd([
            'class_name' => get_class($request),
            'params' => $request->all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

.../sample/request?foo=bar

```php
array:2 [▼
  "class_name" => "Illuminate\Http\Request"
  "params" => array:1 [▼
    "foo" => "bar"
  ]
]
```